# iptables: Marked packets not routed via configured route

Tags: iptables, iproute2

I need to configure a firewall server with two internet lines (A on eth1, B on eth0) and an internal network (C on eth2). Additionally to the default routing table (via A / eth1), I have two routing tables with their own default gateways each.

I can reach the server via internet line A and SSH on port 22, as expected. But when I try to reach it via internet line B, the returning tcp/ip packets are sent via internet line A.

[image: Firewall with two internet connections]

Obviously, when I connect to the server via internet line B, I want it to reply via internet line B.

How can I achieve this?

---

What I have tried so far:
I have configured sshd, so that it listens on a second port (122). I have then added a

```
#!/bin/bash

iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X
ip rule add from all fwmark 1 table 2

ip route flush cache
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 122 -j LOG
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --sport 122 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Now, I can connect to the server via internet line B, but the answers are logged to be returned via internet line A.

---

What I have also tried so far:

I can control the traffic originating from other computers in internal network C to be sent via either internet line A or B - by just marking their packets in the prerouting table:

```
$A -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

This works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup requires usage of PBR (Policy Based Routing). You're using it, but not complete. You can solve you issue by two ways:

- Simple way: just add two rules for every uplink like `ip rule add from <srv-IP-A> table <tbl-A> pref 1001` and `ip rule add from <src-IP-B> table <tbl-B> pref 1002`, where `A` and `B` are corresponded links. It works only for traffic from server itself, because it always reply from same ip address, on which the initial connection request receives.
- Hard way: use the `CONNMARK` target. It will works for all cases. Logic: the conntrack entry is associated with connection, and may contain an additional value inside itself. You can clone this value into/from the firewall mark and use the match in the iptables rules.